# MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016): actual keyboard layout does not jive with input settings.

Tags: macos, keyboard

Got a new MacBook Pro that we can't seem to figure out.

First off, here's the physical keyboard:

[Actual Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA6JB.jpg)

And here's a screenshot of the input settings:

[Keyboard Input Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxK5z.png)

As you can see, the physical keyboard does not line up with the input keyboard. For example, when I try to type a colon, I'm getting a '>'. When I click on the N with a tilde, I'm getting a semi-colon, etc. etc.

I've googled the issue, but I could not find anything on this. What are we missing here? Did I get some sort of international MacBook that I need to return? Is this a settings issue? There doesn't appear to be a way to adjust input settings beyond just choosing a different language (i.e. I can't just configure individual keys any way I want.

Any help you guys can give would be appreciated.

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like you got a non-english macbook pro. I'm not completely sure what language it is, but definitely isn't english. Try returning the product. Attached is a picture of the U.S version of the macbook pro.[image]

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks Tim!